# Flexbox equivalent for fr (fraction) unit

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

What would be the best analogy for `fr`(fraction) unit in a flexbox layout? I was thinking of `flex: 1` but not sure if it is the best match in terms of its growing/shrinking behavior.

What I'm trying to do is to make a fallback for grid layout so that it works in IE11. I have a grid statement `grid-template-columns: 11.25rem 1fr;` that I can't make work in IE (even with Auto-prefixer that adds `-ms-grid-columns` columns still stack on top of each other).

So I was thinking to maybe just implement it in flexbox for IE using something like this:

```
.container {
  max-width: 46rem;

  .parent {
    display: flex;

    & :first-child {
      inline-size: 11.25rem;
    }

    & :last-child {
      flex: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: a fixed with for the firs-child and flex-grow:1 for the last should do it

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've tried it but setting only flex-grow means that flex-basis defaults to auto. And in this way, the second child, that has a lot of text in it, doesn't respect container's width and overflows it.

Comment: you add flex-basis:0 then

Comment: @TemaniAfif, well, then it basically becomes `flex:1` ain't it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turned out `flex: 1` works for my needs.

It's a shorthand for `flex: 1 1 0px;` so

`flex-grow: 1` lets it grow when there is extra space.
`flex-shrink: 1` lets it shrink when there is not enough space.
`flex-basis: 0px` allows it to have width defined by its content with respect to its container's width.